# Different nuances of the verb LOOK

Tags: словоупотребление

In English, when we want someone to direct their gaze in a certain direction in order to take a photo, for example, or to see a specific angle of their face, we tell them to **look over here**, **look that way**, **look at me**, etc. Can **(по)смотреть** (or (an)other ***смотр** or ***гляд** verb(s)) be used in this way, or is there a more idiomatic way to express this in Russian?

Comment: In English there is look, watch, glance, stare, etc.

Comment: @Anixx: not quite. If you want someone to face the camera, for example, you can't say "glance here" or "stare at me" - I don't think you read my post :)

Comment: the same is in Russian.

Comment: @Anixx: Alrighty then! I guess I just didn't understand why you were answering my question about a specific subset of Russian verbs in a specific usage by giving me general list of verbs that exist in my own language :)

Answer (score 3):

The most commom verbs meaning "look here, at me"are

> *смотри*,*смотрите сюда*, *посмотрите сюда*.

If you are inviting to look at something, you say

> *смотри-ка*,*посмотри на это*,*глянь сюда*,*глянь-ка на него* (very colloquial ) *взгляни*,*взгляните на это*,*гляди* (often used by people in villages,but rarely in cities now),*погляди на него*.

When someone takes pictures, he usually says,especially to children:

> *Внимание,сейчас вылетит птичка!*(When you say 'Say "cheese"!).

Answer (score 2):

To make someone look in the certain direction verbs of the root -смотр- and -гляд- can be used. The most often used here will be [смотреть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) like "посмотри вот туда", "смотри, как красиво".

> **СМОТРЕТЬ**, смотрю, смотришь; смотренный; *несов*.
>   1. *на кого-что и на что.*  Направлять взгляд, чтобы увидеть кого-что-н., глядеть.
>   Смотреть на собеседника.
>   Смотри в окно.

There is a collocation ["смотровая площадка"](http://www.ozhegov.com/words/33261.shtml), which means "площадка для осмотра местности" (a viewing area).
*Посмотреть* can also be used in that same sense.

[Глядеть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) is another way of directing someone's gaze; although in some cases it may sound as a bit deprecated, it has mostly [the same meaning](http://www.ozhegov.com/words/5764.shtml). A way to use it is:

> Взгляни, какой красивый вид! *Look what a beautiful view!*

There are other ways to express something like admire; they may depend on situation, used vocabulary and society. For example:

> Полюбуйтесь, каков вид!
>
> Только взгляните, до чего красиво!

Answer (score 1):

`глядеть` is too dialectic and means rather `to stare in order to perceive` and not with a kind of a blank disinterested stare, therefore not

`посмотреть` is OK like in

> смотри на меня

as well as `повернуть голову` (towards certain direction or object) for taking a shot

Comment: Thank you! By the way, I didn't mean глядеть specifically, I meant any derivative of the root -гляд-.

Comment: technically one can say `взгляни-ка вон туда`, `а-ну сейчас погляди-ка на меня` but it may sound a bit pretentious and playful unless the word `глядеть` is a part of the speaker everyday vocabulary, that's just because the word itself is antiquated